# Make a Movie from Multiple Images in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, video-processing

I have 10 images in the folder say "D:\images\" named as frame1,frame2,...,frame10. I want to make a movie from the color images **with frame rate as per choice**.Also i want to save created video file in .mp4 format at the location "D:\video\".

Is it possible to do so in MATLAB?how?

Comment: This isn't a DSP question. This is a general and a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do using the [VideoWriter class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html).

You easily add frame (Image) using the proper method which is [`writeVideo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.writevideo.html).

After creating a video object, `videoObject` and given an image by `mImage001`, adding frame is done by:

```
writeVideo(videoObject, mImage001);
```

Enjoy...

#### Code Sample

Here is a code sample based on Mathworks documentation with some remarks of mine:

```
% Creating Video Writer Object
writerObj = VideoWriter('peaks.avi');
% Using the 'Open` method to open the file
open(writerObj);

% Creating a figure.
% Each frame will be a figure data
Z = peaks; surf(Z); 
axis tight
set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');

for k = 1:20 
   surf(sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z,Z)
   % Frame includes image data
   frame = getframe;
   % Adding the frame to the video object using the 'writeVideo' method
   writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
end

% Closing the file and the object using the 'Close' method
close(writerObj);
```

This should be straight forward.

Comment: sir,can u explain it using any simple example.because i am getting difficulty in making video of color images like colormap adjustments and  writevideo command.so can u take example

Comment: I added code sample. Enjoy...